# Doing 2 tasks on different threads error C#

Tags: c#, threadpool, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to divide a string array into 2, create 2 threads and search through those arrays on those 2 threads. I know I am creating the threads correctly, and the search function is correct, but I am still getting this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here is the code:

```
// Create first and second array:
string[] firstarray = pieces.Take(pieces.Length / 2).ToArray();
string[] secondarray = pieces.Skip(pieces.Length / 2).ToArray();
string[] results = new string[pieces.Length];
string inputword = textBox5.Text.Trim();

ManualResetEvent[] calls = new ManualResetEvent[2];
calls[0] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
calls[1] = new ManualResetEvent(false);

// Set 2 new threads:
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((t) => {
    // SearchThruPieces searches an array for a string and returns the items
    // that contains the string
    // SearchThruPieces(string[] pieces, string word);
    SearchThruPieces(firstarray, inputword).CopyTo(results, 0);
    calls[0].Set();
});

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((t) => {
    SearchThruPieces(secondarray, inputword).CopyTo(results, firstarray.Length);
    calls[1].Set();
});

WaitHandle.WaitAll(calls);
string firststring = results[0]; // This line throws an exception
```

Now I know this error does not concern any of the threading or the `SearchThruPieces` method because it happens when I use:

```
results[0]
```

It returns the error.

Please help me solve this problem or tell me if their is a better way of doing what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks

Edit:

Here is the code of SearchThruPieces:

```
delegate string[] Search(string[] pieces, string word);

        static Search SearchThruPieces = (string[] pieces, string word) =>
        {
            object locker = new object();
            lock (locker)
            {
                int a = 0;
                string[] afterpieces = new string[pieces.Length];
                for (int b = 0; b < (pieces.Length / 4); b++)
                {
                    if (pieces[a].Trim().ToLower().Contains(word.Trim().ToLower()) && pieces[a].Trim().Length > 0)
                    {
                        afterpieces[a] = pieces[a].Trim();
                        afterpieces[a + 1] = pieces[a + 1].Trim();
                        afterpieces[a + 2] = pieces[a + 2].Trim();
                        afterpieces[a + 3] = pieces[a + 3].Trim();
                    }

                    a += 4;
                }
                return afterpieces;
            }
        };
```

Edit 2:

So I set a break-point on:

```
afterpieces[a] = pieces[a].Trim();
```

To see if it gets called, and it does. I think the error has something to do with setting results[] to the result of `SearchThruPieces`.

Comment: When do you call results[0] ?

Comment: @Slugart I call results[0] a couple lines after WaitHandle.WaitAll(calls), in between I create a ListViewItem.

Comment: Does the result have any data ? Looks like results does not have any data when you try to get the data in the index 0.

Comment: btw, asking for `textBox5.Text` etc on a worker thread **is not safe**; you should only talk to the UI *from the UI thread*

Comment: The result of SearchThruPieces is either a 0 lenght array or contains empty elements.

Comment: Which line **that you are showing us** throws this exception?

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok thanks, I changed my code and post around.

Comment: @Slugart I will test now if the result of SearchThruPieces has any data.

Comment: What happens if you comment out everything between `string inputword = ...` and `string firststring = results[0]`?

Comment: @AntonTykhyy If I comment out all those things I get the same error...

Comment: @AntonTykhyy `new string[x];` will define an array which contains x null references.

Comment: So I am 100% sure that SearchThruPieces returns a string array that does contain data, but the only thing I am worried about is that I am using a lock in it, which might change some things around. I could post the code in the post if you want.

Comment: @MatthewRz instead of that assert that the array has non-null items in it before calling CopyTo.

Comment: Does 'pieces' have any elements in it?

Comment: @GregRos Yes, pieces does have elements in it.

Comment: Please post the code of the SearchThruPieces method.

Comment: The locker object is created for each call of the delegate, so it makes no difference. Are you remembering to initialize the result variable, so it isn't null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `pieces` has elements defined in it, and assuming the string you're searching for is actually in `pieces`, and assuming the search string is actually in `secondarray` after the array division, then `results` will be empty because your second `ThreadPool` call passes `firstarray` again, not `secondarray`.

Comment: It turns out that the code in my compiler passes secondarray to the ThreadPool, not firstarray again. Wierd, must have gone wrong in the copy-paste.

Comment: Second possible problem: if, as above, the search string is in 'secondarray' and 'SearchThruPieces' correctly returns the elements to 'result[]', they will start at result[firstarray.Length], not result[0].